# Java ArrayList of Objects not getting the FinalList of items count

Tags: java, arraylist, size

I am working on a java code which will retrieve all the categories and corresponding media located in the categories. I am getting all the categories as list properly,  but not the media which is inside. The total count of media is 600+. Individually its printing the count properly. But at the end its returning only 226. Please help me solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
private static List<KalturaCategoryEntry> getCategoryMedia(
        List<KalturaCategory> openCategoryList) throws KalturaApiException,
        ParseException {
    List<KalturaCategoryEntry> categoryEntries = new ArrayList<KalturaCategoryEntry>();
    for (KalturaCategory category : openCategoryList) {
        KalturaCategoryEntryFilter categoryEntryFilter = new KalturaCategoryEntryFilter();
        categoryEntryFilter.categoryIdEqual = category.id;
        // categoryEntryFilter.statusEqual =
        // KalturaCategoryEntryStatus.ACTIVE;
        KalturaCategoryEntryListResponse categoryEntryList = getCategoryEntry(categoryEntryFilter);
        if (categoryEntryList.totalCount != 0) {
            System.out.println("categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>"
                    + categoryEntryList.totalCount);
            for (KalturaCategoryEntry entry : categoryEntryList.objects) {
                if (entry != null) {
                    categoryEntries.add(entry);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total Media ------- >" + categoryEntries.size());
    return categoryEntries;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>368
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>2
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>8
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>2
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>1
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>17
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>18
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>1
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>53
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>37
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>1
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>2
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>1
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>7
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>7
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>6
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>53
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>2
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>39
categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>1
Total Media ------- >226
```

Comment: There might be `null`'s inside the list.

Comment: It seems that you loop over lists that do contain lists of  some Objects?

Comment: And you need to elaborate more. There is no clue to find out the issue.

Comment: No no. The list of objects are there. I am doing null checks.If you see the output categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>1, 6, 53 etc...are the objects which are separately returning from each category but at the end its showing only 226. I am not understanding whats happening.

Comment: Downvote beacuse the title is not describing the problem or asking any question

Comment: `categoryEntryList.totalCount` I really suspect this. Check weather this is updating along with list or not.

Comment: Yeah, but you do iterate 226 times over the List. Where should the `List.size` function get the information of the function totalCount from?

Answer (score 2):

Probably, there is a difference between `categoryEntryList.totalCount` and `categoryEntryList.objects.size()`

Try change your

```
System.out.println("categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>"
                    + categoryEntryList.totalCount);
```

To

```
System.out.println("categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>"
                    + categoryEntryList.objects.size());
```

You will have the real count.

Comment: If it worked for you you can accept it as the answer ;)

Comment: I did that by just clicking on the up button.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if (categoryEntryList.totalCount != 0) {
    System.out.println("categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>"
            + categoryEntryList.totalCount);
    for (KalturaCategoryEntry entry : categoryEntryList.objects) {
        categoryEntries.add(entry);
    }
}
```

instead of

```
if (categoryEntryList.totalCount != 0) {
    System.out.println("categoryEntryList.totalCount ------>"
            + categoryEntryList.totalCount);
    for (KalturaCategoryEntry entry : categoryEntryList.objects) {
        if (entry != null) {
            categoryEntries.add(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

If you get a different result, then as @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ suggest, you have null values in your objects list that `categoryEntryList.totalCount` doesn't propertly manage.